# Extra Square in Partial Fraction

Tags: partial-fractions

So I understand why this is true:
$$
\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B}{x+1}
$$

But there's a special rule in partial fraction that I just couldn't get it. When you have a term that is squared, I must add another fraction with the term squared in the denominator:
$$
\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)^2} = \frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B}{x+1} + \frac{C}{(x+1)^2}
$$

Why? Shouldn't $(x+1)^2$ be treated like $(x+1)(x+1)$ and do this instead?:
$$
\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)^2} = \frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B}{x+1} + \frac{C}{x+1}
$$

Why is the extra square needed?

---

To visualize it easier, I have tried to substitute terms with letters.

$$
\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)}\\
\text{Let x+2 be X, x+1 be Y:}\\
 = \frac{A}{X} + \frac{B}{Y}\\
 = \frac{AY+BX}{XY}
$$

And I can do the same thing for this:

$$
\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)^2} = \frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)(x+1)}\\
\text{Let x+2 be X, x+1 be Y, x+1 be Z:}\\
 = \frac{A}{X} + \frac{B}{Y} + \frac{C}{Z}\\
 = \frac{AYZ + BXZ + CXY}{XYZ}\\
\\
\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)(x+1)} = \frac{AYZ + BXZ + CXY}{XYZ}\\
x = AYZ + BXZ + CXY
$$

I don't see any problem in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the zero $x=-1$ of the denominator has a multiplicity of $2$, the partial fractions must contain the $2$nd power of $(x+1)$. Though there is no necessity that the partial fraction must contain $1$st power of $(x+1)$.

In your explanation, $$\frac{B}{x+1} + \frac{C}{x+1} = \frac{B+C}{x+1}$$
$$\frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B+C}{x+1} = \frac{A(x+1)+(x+2)(B+C)}{(x+2)(x+1)}$$
Check the denominator here. What is the power of $(x+1)$ here ? It is $1$. But it should have been $2$ right? Where did it vanish ? It vanished because of the mistake that you have done in neglecting the repeated root in denominator. Here the multiplicity of the zero $x=-1$ is just $1$, where it should have been $2$.

You can refer [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Illustration) if still in doubt.

**EDIT:** Since you are not fully aware on how partial fraction decomposition works. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "multiplicity of the zero x = -1 is just 1". Can you explain it more please?

Comment: The explanation of lsp is the right one.

Comment: In your example, you added $\frac{B}{x+1}+\frac{C}{x+1}$ and the denominator remains the same. But no one says that I have to do it like this though; I can do $\frac{B(x+1)+C(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$ and everything is still valid.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 But the fraction you just mentioned in you comment is reducible ! You can cancel out $(x+1)$ from numerator and denominator.

Comment: @lsp - But no one says I have to cancel them out.

Comment: Ok. I'll explain you. But first explain me why you are writing $\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B}{x+1}$ and not $\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)} = A + B$

Comment: Well it's because if you multiply the denominators together, the denominator in the left will be the same as the right. Since they are the same, I will be left with $x=A(x+1)+B(x+2)$.

Comment: Why not write it as just $A+B$ ? As we can re write $A+B$ as $\frac{A(x+1)}{x+1}+\frac{B(x+2)}{x+2}$. This will still give the denominator as $(x+1)(x+2)$. What do you comment on this ?

Comment: @lsp - Writing it as $A+B$ works too, but doesn't it mean that the fraction is equal to $0$? Okay something doesn't sound right here.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 So did you get it now ? What it will lead you to when you consider reducible fractions ?

Comment: Yea I get it now, we add the square to prevent getting 0's. But every step I did is correct, and if every step is true then the statement $\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)}=0$ should be true as well. Why isn't it the case here?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Just go through the link that I have provided. That will make things very clear for you.

Comment: @lsp - The Wikipedia article doesn't explain why $\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)}=0$ is false...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not only $\frac{x}{(x+2)(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B}{x+1}$, according to your logic all fractions in such form are $0$ which is absolutely false.

Comment: @lsp - I know it is definitely false, and I understand now why the square is needed, but I want to know where in between the process went wrong since each step is true.

Comment: Your steps went wrong from where you started using reducible fractions, i.e., fractions of the form $\frac{A(x+1)}{(x+1)}$. In your case in the first step itself where you have used $\frac{C}{(x+1)}$ assuming it to be $\frac{C(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$

Comment: @lsp - But $\frac{C}{x+1}$ *is* the same as $\frac{C(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$... isn't it?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Instead of just bluntly trying to disprove everything just take a moment and think as to what happens when you do that here.

Comment: @lsp - Okay I will take a look at it again later. Anyway thank you so much for explaining the reason why the square is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

$$
\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x+1}+\frac{C}{x+1} = \frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B+C}{x+1}=\frac{A(x+1)+(B+C)(x+1)}{(x+1)(x+2)}
$$

This does not contain the $(x+1)^2$ term in the denominator so does not cover all possible solutions.  Which is why it does not work.

While

$$
\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x+1}+\frac{C}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{A(x+1)^2+B(x+1)(x+2)+C(x+2)}{(x+1)^2(x+2)}
$$

Does.

We can expand the numerator

$$
\begin{align}
A(x+1)^2+B(x+1)(x+2)+C(x+2) &= A(x^2+2x+1)+B(x^2+3x+2)+C(x+2)\\
&= (A+B)x^2+(2A+3B+C)x+(A+2B+2C)
\end{align}$$

Which we can use to find A, B and C

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B}{x+1}+\frac{C}{x+1}=\frac{A(x+1)^2+B(x+1)(x+2) + C(x+1)(x+2)}{(x+2((x+1)^2}$

Then

$x=Ax^2+2Ax+A+Bx^2+3Bx+2B+Cx^2+3Cx+2C$

and

$A+B+C=0$

$2A+3B+3C=1$

$A+2B+2C=0$

You can try to solve this system.

Comment: It is unsolvable. Is it because of this reason that we have to add the square?

Comment: This is the only reason.

Answer (score 0):

The common denominator must be $(x+2)(x+1)^2$. You cannot obtain it from your second representation.

Comment: If I multiply $(x+2)(x+1)(x+1)$ I still get $(x+2)(x+1)^2$ back though.

Comment: @Derek Yes, but it's not the lowest common multiple of the denominators.

Comment: The proper cmmon denominator in the second case is $(x+2)(x+1)$

Comment: @kmitov - Indeed the common denominator is $(x+2)(x+1)$, but why would you care about common denominator? I mean you can still multiply everything like they are different and solve the equation at the end.

Comment: But you can try and see the result.

Comment: @kmitov - Indeed the common denominator is (x+2)(x+1), but why would you care about common denominator? I mean you can still multiply everything like they are different and solve the equation at the end. –  Derek 朕會功夫 16 mins ago You have to care.