# Partial Fraction Decomposition of A/[x(x-a)^m]

Tags: partial-fractions

I'm having difficulty understanding why / how to go about proving the fact that a partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{A}{x(x-a)^m}=\frac{A_1}{x}+\frac{A_2}{(x-a)^1}+\frac{A_3}{(x-a)^2}+ ... +\frac{A_m}{(x-a)^m}$ .

Why is it not just something like $\frac{A}{x(x-a)^m}=\frac{A_1}{x}+\frac{A_2}{(x-a)^m}$?

[image: A screenshot from Paul's Online Math Notes pertaining to said statement.]

I've read an answer on MSE : [Partial Fraction Decomposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672430/partial-fraction-decomposition) but I don't understand it. Is there a way of proving this statement without resorting to vector spaces and basis thingamajigs?

Comment: `Why is it not just something like` Simply put, because it just doesn't work out. Try to determine $A_1, A_2$ so that your "simple" form holds identically, and you'll soon find that it's not possible.

Comment: So in order to prove this statement I have to systematically prove by contradiction every other instance where the number of terms is < m that they don't work?

Comment: No, it's not a matter of trial and error. But it's not entirely clear whether you want to *use* or you want to *prove* the form of partial fraction decomposition. Either way, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the simplest case
$\dfrac1{x(x-a)^2}
$.

If
$\dfrac1{x(x-a)^2}
=\dfrac{u}{x}+\dfrac{v}{(x-a)^2}
$
then
$\dfrac{u}{x}+\dfrac{v}{(x-a)^2}
=\dfrac{u(x-a)^2+vx}{x(x-a)^2}
=\dfrac{ux^2+(v-2ua)x+ua^2}{x(x-a)^2}
$
and you need to have
$u = 0, v-2ua=0, ua^2 = 1$.

This is three equations in two unknowns
and, in this case,
has no solution.

You need three parameters,
which are gotten by writing
$\dfrac1{x(x-a)^2}
=\dfrac{u}{x}+\dfrac{v}{x-a}+\dfrac{w}{(x-a)^2}
$.

This becomes
$1
=u(x-a)^2+vx(x-a)+wx
$
and this can be solved for
$u, v, w$.

The general case is
$\dfrac1{x(x-a)^m}
=\dfrac{c}{x}+\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{b_j}{(x-a)^j}
$
and this can be solved
for
$c$ and the $b_j$.

If we clear fractions,
this becomes
$1
= c(x-a)^m+\sum_{j=1}^m b_jx(x-a)^{m-j}
= c(x-a)^m+x\sum_{j=1}^m b_j(x-a)^{m-j}
$.

Setting $x=0$ gives
$1 = c(-a)^m$
so
$c = \dfrac1{(-a)^m}
$
and
$1
= (x-a)^m(-a)^{-m}+x\sum_{j=1}^m b_j(x-a)^{m-j}
$.

Putting $x=a$ gives
$1
= ab_m
$
so
$b_m = \dfrac1{a}
$.

The successive $b_j$
can be similarly determined.